# Snakemake invalid syntax

Tags: snakemake

I am getting crazy with snakemake. I tried all types of ways, using config file etc, but nothing works and I cannot understand exactly how to detect the error checking line by line.

```
HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX = "/media/jim/Elements/Happy/index/genome_chromosomes"

SAMPLES, *_=glob_wildcards('/media/jim/Elements/Happy/test/tissue/trimmed/{sample}_1.fastq.gz')

rule all:
    input: expand("{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES)

rule hisat2:
    input:
        hisat2_index=expand(f"{HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX}.{{ix}}.ht2l", ix=range(1, 8)),
        fastq1="/media/jim/Elements/Happy/test/tissue/trimmed/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="/media/jim/Elements/Happy/test/tissue/trimmed/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = "{sample}.bam",
        txt = "{sample}.txt",
    log: "/snakemake_log.txt"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        "hisat2 -p {threads} -x {HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX}"
        " -1 {input.fastq1} -2 {input.fastq2}  --summary-file {output.txt} |"
        "samtools sort -@ {threads} -o {output.bam}"
```

Now the error I get is:

```
SyntaxError in line 11 of /media/jim/Elements/Happy/test/Snakefile:
invalid syntax
```

The error might be some small thing, but I cannot understand which......
The problem is that I have many tissues, so I have to make working at least this simple example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

- `log: "/snakemake_log.txt"` should contain the same wildcards as the other directives. E.g. `log: "/{sample}.snakemake_log.txt"` otherwise snakemake doesn't know where to write the sample specific logs
- I think the string formatting with `f"..."` has been introduced in python 3.6. Maybe you have python < 3.6?

Comment: yes, I am using python 3.5.1 I think...but I have python 3.6 installed, is there a way: a. to substitute f"..." b. to indicate which python to use?thanksss so much!

Comment: I usually use virtual environment: virtualenv -p python3 .venv then source .venv/bin/activate

Comment: I would use a more portable string-formatting syntax. The old-fashioned style would be `expand("%s.{ix}.ht2l" % HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX, ix=range(1, 8))`

Comment: Wow, I hope it is running, at least it doesn't through an error!!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Snakemake has broken support for Python 3.5 trough the use of format strings (they were only introduced in Python 3.6). There is already an issue for this: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/435

I found that the recent Snakemake versions 5.19 and 5.18 both had this issue, but 5.17 worked fine.

So to fix this, run (after activating your virtual environment)

```
pip install snakemake==5.17
```